# How to update Browserslist in older Babel version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am attempting to update the browser support for a React app that is using React 16.8.4, Webpack 3.11.0 and Babel 6.26.0. I have updated the Browserslist query to the following

```
  "browserslist": [
    "chrome >= 66",
    "edge >= 88",
    "firefox >= 60",
    "safari >= 11",
    "last 2 versions",
    ">2%",
    "not dead"
  ]
```

And then run the query on my local machine and the support browser list I get back is pretty short and shows nothing after 2019.

```
and_ff 66
and_qq 1.2
and_uc 11.8
android 67
android 4.4.3-4.4.4
baidu 7.12
chrome 74
chrome 73
chrome 72
chrome 71
chrome 70
chrome 69
chrome 68
chrome 67
chrome 66
edge 18
edge 17
firefox 66
firefox 65
firefox 64
firefox 63
firefox 62
firefox 61
firefox 60
ie 11
ie_mob 11
ios_saf 12.2
ios_saf 12.0-12.1
kaios 2.5
op_mini all
op_mob 46
opera 58
opera 57
safari 12.1
safari 12
safari 11.1
safari 11
samsung 9.2
samsung 8.2
```

This makes sense because the version of Babel is that old.

My question is this, how can I get the list to include the recent versions of these browsers? And will Babel 3 know what to do with it?

Any help and/or direction will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Gene